# Query in finding the data within the row

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I need to write a query,
subjects table

```
1. Id=1  name= subject 1, teacher_id = 1, course_id = 1,;
2. Id=1  name= subject 2, teacher_id = 2, course_id = 3;
3. Id=1  name= subject 3, teacher_id = 3, course_id = 4 
4. Id=1  name= subject 3, teacher_id = 4, course_id = 5 ;(exclude)
```

I have a student_exclusion table with student_id, course_id and teacher_id.This model is for the student doesnot want to see the subjects from subjects whose teacher_id and course_id are these,

```
student_id = 1, teacher_id = 3,course_id=4
student_id = 1, teacher_id = 4,course_id=5
student_id = 2, teacher_id = 3,course_id=5
```

I need to display the all the subjects except 3 and 4(which means I need to display the subjects where teacher_id!=Student_exclusion.teacher_id and course_id!=student_exclusion.course_id). How can I write the query? I can get the teacher_id and course_id from here, But I need to check with a particular row . All I want to do is, get all the teacher_id and course_id from student_exclusion table, and then From subject model (Get all the subjects where teacher_id and course_id != studentExcludedCourseTeacher). Its like , Student add the teacher course id in the (I dont want to see the subjects where course=1 and teacher = 1). (From a row )

```
$studentExcludedCourseTeacher= StudentExclusion::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get('teacher_id', 'course_id');
$subjectList = Subject::->where(function ($query) use ($studentExcludedCourseTeacher) {
??               
);
 })->get();
```

Comment: where are subject details coming from?

Comment: Added manually by admin front backend @AnkitSharma I am not able to edit the post but tha name=subject1, subject2 subbject3

Comment: Do you want to join the second table with the first table by the column student_id first?

Comment: @NabinaKhadka click on edit button just bellow tags

Comment: Ticket from which table?
Your first table is for subjects,
And second one is for student_exclusion.
Would you please give an example output what you are expecting?

Comment: I want to display the subject, where teacher_id and course_id doesnot include instudent _exclusion table. Like i have a subjects where name subject1, teacher_1=1(anish), course=1(science). If student has added teacher_id=1 and course_id=1 in student_exclusion table(means he doesnot want to see the subjects whose teacher is anish and course is science(combination of course and teacher from subject table). @SAhmedNaim .Student_exclusion table is for hide.Student doesnot want to see anything from the subject that has student_exclusion.teacher_id and student_exclusion.subject_id from subject table

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all Subjects.
2. Get all Student Exclusion.
3. Filter Subjects in such a way that Student Exclusion doesn't have any entry belongs to the each entry of teacher_id and course_id at a time.

```
$subjects = Subject::all();

$studentExclusion = StudentExclusion::all();

$result = $subjects->filter(function($item) use ($studentExclusion) {
    $data = $studentExclusion->where("teacher_id", $item->teacher_id)->where("course_id", $item->course_id)->count() ?? 0;

    if($data == 0) return $item;
});

return $result;
```

Building of your data set locally:

```
$subjects = collect([
            [
                "name"  => "subject 1",
                "teacher_id" => 1,
                "course_id" => 1
            ], [
                "name"  => "subject 2",
                "teacher_id" => 2,
                "course_id" => 3
            ], [
                "name"  => "subject 3",
                "teacher_id" => 3,
                "course_id" => 4
            ], [
                "name"  => "subject 3",
                "teacher_id" => 4,
                "course_id" => 5
            ]
        ]);

        $studentExclusion = collect([
            [
                "student_id" => 1,
                "teacher_id" => 3,
                "course_id"  => 4
            ], [
                "student_id" => 1,
                "teacher_id" => 4,
                "course_id"  => 5
            ], [
                "student_id" => 2,
                "teacher_id" => 3,
                "course_id"  => 5
            ],
        ]);

        $result = $subjects->filter(function($item) use ($studentExclusion) {
            $data = $studentExclusion->where("teacher_id", $item["teacher_id"])->where("course_id", $item["course_id"])->count() ?? 0;

            if($data == 0) return $item;
        });

        return $result->pluck("name");
```

Output:

```
[
    "subject 1",
    "subject 2"
]
```